# Increased used of RAM memory when loading images

Tags: android, android-image

When loading an image, if the file is in the R.drawable folder of the app we can do:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led);
```

To load the image given the path I use (path could be: imagePath = '/storage/emulated/0/NewFolder/image.png':

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getPath());
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

This increases a lot of RAM memory used, and never decreases.

Am I doing it right? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: Have you considered using an image loading library that handles compression?

Comment: use bitmapOption.inSampleSize to reduce the image size on memory depend on screen

Comment: use Picasso https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: developer google : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create a bitmap explicitly make sure you recycle it when you dont need it anymore with:

```
bitmap.recycle()
```

Usually this is called on the activity/fragment/viewmodel ondestroy methods. In case of the first one Android does this automatically, but when you explicitly create a bitmap it stays in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution of this type of issue is use Lazy loading

[Lazy Loading Example](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112)

Answer (score 0):

You have done right thing to add it as a separate questions. I think you can use [Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) lib to load a local or any given image url to your imageView.